# Компьютер видит девайс, а Андроид Студио нет

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-studio

Здравствуйте. Возникла следующая проблема. Компьютер видит планшет при подключении по USB, в adb все нормально отображается. Режим разработчика на планшете включен. Однако Андроид Студио планшет не видит. Операционка Ubuntu 14.04. В чем может быть проблема?

РЕШЕНО
Помогла перезагрузка сервера adb

Всем огромное спасибо!

Comment: а что говорит команда `adb devices`?

Comment: List of devices attached 
0928b053 device

Comment: а в `udev` добавляли правила? Настраивали по [этой инструкции](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)

Comment: Да, в udev тоже все добавлено

Comment: Есть вероятность, что они стучатся в **разные** `adb`. У вас он точно всего один, у Студии нет своего? Сделайте `which adb`.

Comment: /usr/bin/adb   Пишет такое. Вроде только один

Comment: @RaVee, напишите пожалуйста ответ в ответ, а не в вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

На девайсе поиграйся с параметрами "USB подключения к компьютеру"

Мне помогло только когда я снял обе галочки с пунктов "подключать как медиа устройтво" и "камера PTP" пока стояла хоть одна галочка Android Studio девайс не видела